# Objects are not valid as a React child - having to access to two children

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I used the lookup function from mongodb and my output consists of two objects. It successfully retrieved via Postman, but Iam unable to display it on the react app.

This is the backend code to get the output from monogodb.

```
  router.get("/employeepoints", (req, res) => {
  let empno = req.params.name;
  employees.aggregate([{ 
      $lookup: {
        from:"assignment_assignedtostaffs",
        localField:"empno",
        foreignField:"emp_no",
        as:"progress"
        }}  
      ])
    .exec((err, check) => {
      var l = check.length;
      return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        check: check,
        l: l,
      });
    });
});
```

Output from Postman

```json
{
   "success": true,
   "check": [
      {
         "_id": "6138f90bcf5f00948da795bb",
         "empno": 69,
         "name": "Nandasena",
         "progress":[
            {
               "_id": "6139a1336d16d204cc9b7504",
               "assignment_name": "Assignment2",
               "client_no": "clie3",
               "execid": "exec20",
               "place_of_engagement": "California",
               "distance": 4,
               "date_of_allocation": "2021-09-02T00:00:00.000Z",
               "deadline": "2021-09-18T00:00:00.000Z",
               "emp_no": 69,
               "progress": "Working",
               "__v": 0,
               "travel_allowance": 350
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Getting the above output via React. I can access the elements in check but not progress. How do I access the elements in progress as shown above.

```
            <tbody class="tbody1">
              {this.state.employee.map((employees, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>
                    <a href={``} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                      {employees.empno}
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>{employees.name}</td>
                  <td>{employees.email}</td>
                  <td>{employees.commencement_date}</td>
                  <td>{employees.progress.distance}</td>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>
}
```

Comment: `employess.progress` is an array. Map through the items to access the data.

Comment: how do I loop through an array which is already looped?Will really helpful if you can help me...tried everything possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop through the `employees.progress` array to return a new `td` cell for every item in the array and using the `id` as the `key`.

```
...
<td>{employees.commencement_date}</td>
{employees.progress.map(item => (
    <td key={item.id}>
        {item.distance}
    </td>
))}
<td>1</td>
```